# Join Table whether Not Null and Null

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables:

> Table 1: Wilayah

```
wilayah_id                  wilayah_name
    1                         wilayah_1
    2                         wilayah_2
```

> Table 2: Area

```
area_id             wilayah_id            area_name
   1                     1                  area_1
   2                     1                  area_2
   3                     2                  area_3
   4                     1                  area_4
```

> Table 3: Rayon

```
rayon_id          wilayah_id           area_id          rayon_name
    1                   1                   1               rayon_1
    2                   2                   3               rayon_2
```

> Table 4: Penyulang

```
penyulang_id      wilayah_id       area_id        rayon_id      penyulang_name
    1                  1               1             null           penyulang_1
    2                  1               null            1            penyulang_2
    3                  2               3              null          penyulang_3
```

How to join these 4 tables using single query, so the result will look like these?

> Result that I expect.

```
penyulang_id   wilayah_name      area_name       rayon_name      penyulang_name
      1           wilayah_1       area_1          null           penyulang_1
      2           wilayah_1         null          rayon_1       penyulang_2
      3           wilayah_2        area_3         null            penyulang_3
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT
    penyulang_id,
    wilayah_name,
    area_name,
    rayon_name,
    penyulang_name
FROM
    wilayah
INNER JOIN area USING(wilayah_id)
INNER JOIN rayon USING (wilayah_id, area_id)
INNER JOIN penyulang USING (wilayah_id, area_id,rayon_id)
```

but display empty  result

Comment: `SELECT penyulang_id, wilayah_name, area_name, rayon_name, penyulang_name FROM wilayah INNER JOIN area USING(wilayah_id) INNER JOIN rayon USING (wilayah_id, area_id) INNER JOIN penyulang USING (wilayah_id, area_id,rayon_id)`   return empty

Comment: Please add that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    penyulang_id,
    wilayah_name,
    area_name,
    rayon_name,
    penyulang_name
FROM
    Penyulang p
    LEFT JOIN Wilayah w ON w.wilayah_id=p.wilayah_id
    LEFT JOIN Area a ON a.area_id=p.area_id
    LEFT JOIN Rayon r ON r.rayon_id=p.rayon_id
ORDER BY penyulang_id ASC
```

This simply centers the query on the Penyulang table and joins each column to the corresponding table. The `LEFT JOIN` ensures data will be returned if the join fails (i.e. the value on the Penyulang table is null).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t4.penyulang_id,t1.wilayah_name,t2.area_name,t3.rayon_name,
t4.penyulang_name
from wilayah t1 inner join area t2 on t1.wilayah_id =t2.t1.wilayah_id 
inner join rayon t3 on t2.wilayah_id =t3.wilayah_id
inner join penyulang t4 on t3.wilayah_id = t4.wilayah_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want all rows from Penyulang.

And for each row returned, you want

- a lookup to single row from (based on primary key of) Wilayah
- a lookup to single row from (based on primary key of) Area
- a lookup to single row from (based on primary key of) Rayon

It looks like some of your foreign key references are NULL.

So it looks like you just need to use "outer joins"... return the row from Penyulang even if there isn't a matching row in the other tables.

The **`LEFT`** keyword specifies an outer join operation, where a row from the left side is returned even when a matching row from the right side isn't returned.

```
SELECT p.penyulang_id
     , w.wilayah_name
     , a.area_name
     , r.rayon_name
     , w.penyulang_name
  FROM Penyulang p
  LEFT
  JOIN Wilayah w
    ON w.wilayah_id = p.wilayah_id
  LEFT
  JOIN Area a
    ON a.area_id = p.area_id
  LEFT
  JOIN Rayon r
    ON r.rayon_id = r.rayon_id
 ORDER BY p.penyulang_id
```